# Processing PDF export: How do I export visible, not-covered graphic elements only?

Tags: pdf, vector, processing

I have created 3D graphics in Processing with rectangle shapes (with a white fill and a black stroke) placed at different z-depths, overlapping each other.

When I export the sketch canvas to a PDF with **beginRaw()** and **endRaw()**, I would like only the "flattened" 2D version of the graphics, meaning that the rectangle edges that are covered by the fill of other rectangles shouldn't be included in the PDF. If you use Illustrator or Inkscape, this is sort of the equivalent of subtracting one shape from another.

However, the exported PDF contains *all* the rectangle edges.

Is there a way for me to export to a PDF where all the lines that are hidden behind the white fill of other shapes is excluded from the PDF? (I don't need to export the fill as rectangles since the graphics is for a pen plotter)

You can try out this simplified code example to see what happens. I would like the PDF to look like what I see in the canvas window in Processing.

```
import processing.pdf.*;

void setup() {
  size(400, 400, P3D);
  background(255);

  stroke(0);
  fill(255);

  noLoop();
}

void draw() {
  beginRaw(PDF, "output.pdf");  
  camera(width/2, height/2, 200, width/2, height/2, 0, 0, 1, 0);  
  translate(0, 0, -10);

  beginShape();
  vertex(100, 100);
  vertex(200, 100);
  vertex(200, 200);
  vertex(100, 200);
  endShape(CLOSE);

  translate(0, 0, 10);

  beginShape();
  vertex(150, 150);
  vertex(250, 150);
  vertex(250, 250);
  vertex(150, 250);
  endShape(CLOSE);

  endRaw();
}
```